# OData Filter by Multi value 'in()' not working

Tags: vue.js, odata, sap-gateway

I'm using OData Filter Client V2 to filter different product by passing keyword and different filter for example based on 'origin' or 'size', want to achieve like this

```
$format=json&$top=50&$filter=substringof('COFFE', searchKey) and (origin eq 'BRA' or origin eq 'COL')
```

According to this [light OData docs](https://github.com/Soontao/light-odata/blob/HEAD/docs/API.ODataFilter.md#odatafilter) we can use `in()` so looks like this:

```
$filter=substringof('COFFE', searchKey) and origin in ('BRA', 'COL')
```

The first one with `OR()` works, but the second with `IN()` unfortunately is not working, any idea?

Comment: Any error message? 
or Can you share your repro link?

Answer (score 0):

You are grounding on the [JS OData client help](https://github.com/Soontao/light-odata/blob/HEAD/docs/API.ODataFilter.md#odatafilter), but to support something the agreement must be respected both by client and server and SAP OData implementation differs from the other vendors.

What I see from SAP Gateway documentation is only these forms of `$filter` are supported:

```
SalesOrder?$filter=TwinEntity eq 'null'

SalesOrder?$filter=TwinEntity/property eq 'xyz'

SalesOrders?$filter=EditState ne 2 or (EditState eq 2 and TwinEntity eq null)

SalesOrder?$filter=TwinEntity/<next_navigation>/...<last_navigation> eq 'null'
```

So `in` operator is not supported for filtering Odata properties.

P.S. By the way, in the [ODAta OASIS specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-os-part1-protocol.html#_Toc372793693) I do not see `in` in built-in operators either.